# Which preposition should be used in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which sentence is correct?

> Allocation of a fair proportion of a country's health budget **to**  preventative measures seems to be a wise choice.
>
> Allocation of a fair proportion of a country's health budget **for** preventative measures seems to be a wise choice.

Should I use *for* or *to*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the meaning is

> "A particular amount of money should be used for a particular purpose".

The second sentence corresponds to this meaning.

Comment: what does the first one mean?

Comment: The usage of "to" is incorrect here. You can use "to" with a person or an organization.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either one, but the meaning is not the same.

> Allocation of a fair proportion of a country's health budget **to** preventative measures seems to be a wise choice.

"allocation *to* preventative measures" indicates that the money is allocated from the budget, that will be used to pay for those measures.

> Allocation of a fair proportion of a country's health budget **for** preventative measures seems to be a wise choice

"allocation *for* preventative measures" indicates the *purpose* of the  allocation.